# C# PropertyInfo.GetValue() when the property is a SortedSet<T>

Tags: c#, system.reflection, sortedset, propertyinfo

[I refactored the code and added comments to make it clear. See pic of code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePd6M.png)

UPDATE:  I know the info I provided was a bit flawed so I edited the question.  Nevertheless, how does one get the value from the property when it's a SortedSet?  When I try to iterate over the return from GetValue() it gives me an Argument Null Exception.

Is there a practical way to get the `PropertyInfo.Name` and `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` from a class instance when said property is a `SortedSet<T>`? For example:

The machine class looks like this:

```
public class Machine : IComparable, IComparable<Machine>
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public SortedSet<SubAssembly> SubAssemblies { get; set; } = [];
}
```

I then pull all of the `Machines` from a DB and try to get the property names and values like so:

```
 foreach (var MachineInDB in db.GetRecordList<Machine>(MachinesTable))
 {
     PropertyInfo[] MachineClassProperties = MachineInDB.GetType().GetProperties();

     Console.WriteLine("\n");

     foreach (PropertyInfo MachineProperty in MachineClassProperties)
     {
         
          Console.WriteLine($"{MachineProperty.Name} => {MachineProperty.GetValue(MachineInDB)}");
            
          //this one will print the following when it gets to the problem property
          //SubAssemblies => System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[SubAssembly]

          //If I try to iterate over the SortedSet property, I get an ArgumentNull exception. 
         
     }
 }
```

Every other property in the class prints fine with the above code. If I print each `Machine` from the DB using `ToString()` all of the `SubAssemblies` print perfectly, so no problem pulling the data from the database.

Somehow the `PropertyInfo` element is null when it try to use `reflectance` only on the 'SortedSet'.  Does anyone know how to work around that?  I bet that if I switch to a `List<T>` it would work fine but I really need it to be a `SortedSet<T>`.

I've also tried putting the return value into a 'var' and iterating over it but I end up with an `ArgumentNull` exception.  This is how I know it's just not pulling the object with the `GetValue()` method.

Is it wrong to expect a 'SortedSet' object? What's the right way to do this?

Thank you!

BMET1

Comment: I don't think `IsCollectible` does what you think it does. I'd also *strongly* encourage you to use more idiomatic names - in particular, using `camelCase` for local variables.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet and dbc for the kind (not so kind) feedback.  I realize now that I have a flaw in my IF logic but the question still remains:  how does one get the value from the PropertyType when said property is a SortedSet<t>.  Is the GetValue() Method not right?  I did look at those other links you kindly provided but I couldn't get them to to work myself.  I am new to C# so a more gentle hand would be most helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BMET1 [`PropertyInfo.GetValue()` seems to work just fine](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AJQFMAzAG1oGNgBLAeygG5iyKAFj648ANwCGYUgFsJLABbsotUgF5SKgO6kAsvKUqAFAEoReepzC0DpIwAUwnAA60wwAJ4BJKJdLOnZx8/ZVkDZVpKAHFaYAAVD1dTaNjHFzcOWgBnUxNSAG88UmLSdno7AJdgzkoAOQkZVTUNACIAZQgAIwBBLKzaGU7GdmyWvMLcEqnSSWlK5wA1CUYIJv9A6pTgJZXaIzlFCJhSAG0AXTMi6eKKAE4jABIWgHlO4AkIuBnl1dJOcs8rhABXmO1WAEItgkkiZKAAxCCMRj1RoAXzGIimqLw2NE+AAzOR0Hpwio8BMpqhCVEIOwvl4vvlSABzWI8Uj9YDs3FXG6EtpWYC0OBtWIAHg6PT6AyGHgAfKRJb1+oNhtkCiy2Rytaj1KcziIeQTSNYWFYvkrpaqPKYeEA=)

Comment: It looks to me like you are retrieving the property's value just fine. The problem is that you're trying to print it using Console.WriteLine and ToString. That will just print out the type name. You need to iterate over the list (e.g. using `foreach`) and print each value one at a time.

Comment: Thank you @JohnWu. 

I tried just that and it got the ArgumentNull exception.  This is what tip me off that the value is null.  I saw an example that shows how but it's for a List<t>.  Unfortunately SortedSet<T> is a bit more elusive.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're calling `GetValue` so it's hard to know exactly where the problem is. A [mcve] would make it easier to help you.

Comment: If the value is null then it's quite possible the problem has nothing to do with reflection and you are asking the wrong question. Is your sorted set a [relationship navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations)?

Comment: Thank you @JohnWu.  I know I made a mess of this question but hopefully the picture I've just attached clears things up.  I need to get the values of the SortedSet property.  I can get the names and values for other properties, just not the value for this one.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet.  I've just attached a picture that maybe shows my code better.  I refactored it for clarity but if I made any mistakes please let me know.

Comment: Why are you using reflection at all? Even if your `MachineInDB` variable is an `object` (which I highly doubt), just cast it `var machine = MachineInDB as Machine`.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy you hit the spot!  I had just reached the same conclusion and that was the only way I found it could be done (see my answer below). Another user John Wu also gave me another way.  BTW, I am making a blazor/Maui app and I want to pass in an object and construct the page automatically.  My app will change pages and models so many times that I want to save me the typing.  It's just the way I wanted to go, maybe no the best.  I'm new to programming, specially C# but really liking it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures. It makes it *so* much harder for anyone to try to reproduce the problem. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints before you next post - a [mcve], posted as text rather than as a screenshot, goes a *very* long way to making a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot example, you're passing an `object` to `string.Join` and expecting it to figure out that it is a collection and figure out which properties to output. It won't do that.

If you're explicit about what you want, e.g. by telling the compiler how to treat the object and which properties to output, there is no issue retrieving the SortedSet via Reflection.

If you don't want to cast anything, you can use Reflection on the item that is retrieved from the collection and iterate over its properties too.

```
public class SubAssembly : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompareTo(SubAssembly other) => Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    public int CompareTo(object other) => Name.CompareTo((other as SubAssembly)?.Name);
}

public class Machine 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public SortedSet<SubAssembly> SubAssemblies { get; set; } = new SortedSet<SubAssembly>();
}

public static void Main()
{
    var machine = new Machine
    {
        SubAssemblies = 
        {
            new SubAssembly
            {
                Name = "Foo"
            },
            new SubAssembly
            {
                Name = "Bar"
            }
        }
    };
    var propertyInfo = machine.GetType().GetProperty("SubAssemblies");
    var subAssemblies = propertyInfo.GetValue(machine);
    
    Console.WriteLine("This will contain a type string: " + string.Join(",", subAssemblies));
    Console.WriteLine("Here's your data: " + string.Join(",", ((SortedSet<SubAssembly>)subAssemblies).Select( x => x.Name)));

    //In case you don't want to cast anything
    foreach (var subAssemblyObject in subAssemblies as IEnumerable)
    {
        var type = subAssemblyObject.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Select( x => x.Name + ": " + x.GetValue(subAssemblyObject))));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This will contain a type string: System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[SubAssembly]
Here's your data: Bar,Foo
Name: Bar
Name: Foo
```

See [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zMzjJz) for working example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to know the type to use `GetValue` since it can treat it as an object. I wrote this to test it real quick.

```cs
var m = new Machine();
m.SubAssemblies.Add(new SubAssembly("a"));
m.SubAssemblies.Add(new SubAssembly("c"));
m.SubAssemblies.Add(new SubAssembly("b"));

var machineType = m.GetType(); // or typeof(Machine)
var pi = machineType.GetProperty(nameof(Machine.SubAssemblies));

var value = pi.GetValue(m);

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());

public class Machine : IComparable, IComparable<Machine>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public SortedSet<SubAssembly> SubAssemblies { get; set; } = new();

    public Machine(Guid? id = null)
    {
        Id = id ?? Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public int CompareTo(Machine other) => Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
    public int CompareTo(object obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override string ToString() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
}

public class SubAssembly : IComparable, IComparable<SubAssembly>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public SubAssembly(string name, Guid? id = null)
    {
        Id = id ?? Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
    }
    
    public int CompareTo(SubAssembly other) => Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
    public int CompareTo(object obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override string ToString() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Output:

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[SubAssembly]
```

It's worth noting that you can leave the `value` implicit `var` or if you want to specify the type you can use any implemented interface or a parent class of `SortedSet<T>` and you can view them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=net-8.0).

- `ISet<T>`
- `ICollection<T>`
- `IEnumerable<T>`
- `IEnumerable`
- `ICollection`
- `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`
- `IReadOnlySet<T>`
- `ISerializable`
- `IDeserializationCallback`

Comment: Thank you @Trey.  This is pretty much what I did in the beginning.  Getting the property name is relatively straight forward but how do you get the values behind this property?  I have attached a screenshot that maybe makes the question easier to understand.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE:  I can use `as ICollection` and it will still work.  Close enough I guess.

I think I might have found a PARTIAL answer.

So this can't be done (or at least I can't find a way) with a generic approach.  It seems that you have to know the class type no matter what, and statically type it worse of all. I tried `Type typeOfClass = machineInDB.GetType()`, `typeof(machineInDB.SubAssemblies)`, etc.

`subAssembliesProperty.GetValue(machineInDB) as SortedSet<SubAssembly>;` is the only way it will work.  If you have another solution please let me know because even if it works, it defeats the goal to create a generic way to deconstruct a class instance when one of the properties is a `SortedSet<T>`.

```
    int k = 0;
    foreach (var machineInDB in db.GetRecordList<Machine>(DBCollections.MACHINES.ToString()))
    {
        if (machineInDB != null)
        {
            var subAssembliesProperty = typeof(Machine).GetProperty("SubAssemblies");

            if (subAssembliesProperty != null)
            {
                var subAssemblies = subAssembliesProperty.GetValue(machineInDB) as SortedSet<SubAssembly>;

                int j = 0;

                if (subAssemblies != null)
                    foreach (var subAssembly in subAssemblies)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{k}{j} - {subAssembly}");
                        j++;
                    }
                else Console.WriteLine("It's Null");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
```